# Why is the purpose of "extraRootIds" in apollo cache

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

I work on a projet: React / Apollo Client.
When i want to update cache after mutation (in case of adding new object) i see in apollo developper tools a element called 'extraRootIds'
[image]

```
create({
                variables: { object: film },
                update: (cache, { data }) => {
                    const entity = data.insert_film_one;
                    cache.modify({
                        fields: {
                            search_film: (existingEntityRefs, { readField }) => {
                                const newEntityRef = cache.writeFragment({
                                    id: 'film:{"film_id":' + entity.film_id + '}',
                                    data: entity,
                                    fragment: FILM_CREATE_FIELDS
                                });
                                return [...existingEntityRefs, newEntityRef];
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Everything seems to be ok but i wonder if this extrarootIds is normal.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

From the code comments:

> Well-known singleton IDs like ROOT_QUERY and ROOT_MUTATION are
> always considered to be root IDs during cache.gc garbage
> collection, but other IDs can become roots if they are written
> directly with cache.writeFragment or retained explicitly with
> cache.retain. When such IDs exist, we include them in the __META
> section so that they can survive cache.{extract,restore}.

https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/d9a1039d36801d450a79cb56870f0a351044254b/src/cache/inmemory/types.ts#L91

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure myself since I am somewhat of a beginner Apollo Client user and I couldn't find explicit documentation for it. Searching through the source code though you can see where it is defined:

```
public extract(): NormalizedCacheObject {
const obj = this.toObject();
const extraRootIds: string[] = [];
this.getRootIdSet().forEach(id => {
  if (!hasOwn.call(this.policies.rootTypenamesById, id)) {
    extraRootIds.push(id);
  }
});
if (extraRootIds.length) {
  obj.__META = { extraRootIds: extraRootIds.sort() };
}
return obj;
```

}

https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/cbcf951256b22553bdb065dfa0d32c0a4ca804d3/src/cache/inmemory/entityStore.ts#L276

where `getRootIdSet()` returns:

> a Set of all the ID strings that have been retained by this layer/root *and* any layers/roots beneath it.

So there doesn't seem to be any discernment about what shows up in the Meta storage of the cache. We should probably just assume they are saving every newly altered cache ID there for their own internal use.